# Perl - Confusion between array and hash

Tags: perl

How would you retrieve the 'A' from $this in the following line of code:

```
my $this = { 1 => "A", 2 => "B", 3 => "C" };
```

I am new to Perl and have a couple of questions from the above line.

1) Firstly, is this a valid line of code?

2) What kind of data structure is this? I thought it as hash, but the following line did not give me 'A'.

```
print "$this{1}";
```

Comment: Welcome to Perl.  Note, please remember to always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY Perl script.  It will help you a lot when working with references and complex data structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is an anonymous hash reference.

It's roughly equivalent to saying:

```
my %hash = ( 1 => "A", 2 => "B", 3 => "C" );

my $this = \%hash;
```

To access the value "A", you would use:

```
print $this->{1};
```

For an intro to Perl, I suggest reading the [Modern Perl Book](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/).  The Perl Language section will discuss data structures and references.

Comment: In this case, `$this` would be a *hash reference*.  Then `->` acts here to dereference it.